# Blank responses from Django runserver when checking user permissions

Tags: python, django

I have a similar problem to those listed in

[Django produces blank pages when POST data is sent and Models are accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081573/django-produces-blank-pages-when-post-data-is-sent-and-models-are-accessed)

and

[Nginx connection reset, response from uWsgi lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970495/nginx-connection-reset-response-from-uwsgi-lost)

Here is one of the views in question:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
@occ_update
@checks_status
def hold(request):
    if not request.user.has_perm('orders.hold'):
        return error_response_rollback(NO_PERMISSION_MSG % "hold orders")
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('pk'))
    occ_revision = int(request.POST.get('occ_revision'))
    agent = Agent.get_agent(request.user)
    action = Action(agent=agent, type='hold_order',
                    comments=request.POST.get('comments'))
    action.save()
    order.hold(action, occ_revision)
    return ok_response_commit("Order held successfully.")
```

error_response_rollback rolls back the transaction and returns an HttpResponse with JSON as its contents.

I am adding permission checking to many of my views in my application and when the user does not have the correct permission, a blank response is returned.

However like the questions referenced above, if you put a

```
print request
```

or

```
request.POST
```

statement BEFORE the permission check, the NO_PERMISSION_MSG JSON string is returned to the browser correctly every time (error_response_rollback returns an HttpResponse object with JSON in it.)

You get blank responses when you check permissions before the "print request" and they **do not** have the correct permissions.

You do NOT get blank responses when:

1. the user has the correct permissions
2. a "print request" statement is before any permission check
3. you use Firefox at any point.

The @occ_update and @checks_status decorators just catch exceptions. These problems occur with and without them present.

I'm developing in Chrome and *none of this is an issue in Firefox*.

One page I found suggested overloading the WSGIRequest object to read the request before it is passed to the view but this seems icky to me and I'd rather find out the real solution.

Does anyone know of any fixes/settings to the runserver command to help this issue without hacking on the request? My users are primarily using Chrome so I'd prefer to keep using it... we'll see. Currently developing in Windows using Django 1.3.1

One option I have considered is making another manage.py command to handle this but that, too, seems icky.

Thanks

---

Update:

I have been able to re-organize my code so that any permission checks happen after some bit of data is read from the POST. This seems to have eliminated any symptoms of this problem. It's still not ideal but it is a good alternative to inserting middleware to read the post.  and won't always be possible in all applications.

Please comment if you have a similar situation and just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As saying in the second link in your post, especially http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,196581 : when you works w/ Nginx and uWSGI and get a non-empty POST, always read the `request.POST` before return an HttpResponse. The reason is described in the link.
You don't have to override an handler, just put the `request.POST` line before the return code, or inside some decorator or middleware.
I encountered this issue for production site half a year ago and put the line in a middleware to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'd rather figure out how to do it without wrapping it in middleware though.

Comment: @NicholasOrlowski no problem. It depends on the coverage of the issue in your view code actually. If few lines use it, directly read POST or adjust code a bit are easier and could perform better =)