# Django in Ajax request send empty response if i not used request.POST

Tags: ajax, django

On local server all work normal. But on production not work.

If I send response this way:

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_get_delete_modal(request):
    data = {
        'status': 'success',
        'data': 'test')
    }

data = json.dumps(data)
return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')
```

i get empty response.

But if I send response this way:

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_get_delete_modal(request):
    print request.POST
    data = {
        'status': 'success',
        'data': 'test')
    }

data = json.dumps(data)
return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')
```

I get normal response.

Why is this happening?
Production server running on ngix-uwsgi.

Comment: ``)`` is just a typo?

Comment: Check http://johanneslindenbaum.blogspot.com/2013/02/empty-response-from-django-after-post.html

Comment: Post requets is very small {'key': 'value'}.

Comment: Have the same problem. Solved with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414264/blank-responses-from-django-runserver-when-checking-user-permissions