# Django error when send emails thrue google apps

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a Django application that connect to google apps to send emails. However, few days ago I started to get "Connection reset by peer" error. Sometimes it works, sometimes not... I couldn't find any reason to justify when not works... I am using nginx and uwsgi. Can anybody help me to understand whats going on and how to resolve it?

This same application is running more than 1 month and just now started to give this error.

Here is the log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 155, in password_reset
   form.save(**opts)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 147, in save
   t.render(Context(c)), from_email, [user.email])

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
   connection=connection).send()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/mail/message.py", line 251, in send
   return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 90, in send_messages
   self.close()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in close
   self.connection.quit()

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 730, in quit
   res = self.docmd("quit")

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 363, in docmd
   return self.getreply()

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 337, in getreply
   line = self.file.readline()

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 177, in readline
   chr = self.sslobj.read(1)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 136, in read
   return self._sslobj.read(len)

error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

nginx log:

> ```
> 2011/09/01 12:15:30 [error] 2221#0: *1379 readv() failed (104:
> ```
>
> Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client:
>   187.115.25.63, server: www.site.com, request: "POST
>   /ems/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:9001",
>   host: "www.site.com", referrer:
>   "http://www.site.com/ems/"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are not reading post-data before closing the connection with nginx.

If you cannot modify your app try adding --post-buffering 8192 to your uWSGI command line to force UWSGI reading post-data automatically

Comment: Does post-buffering also work if the client is sending a body with a GET request?