# Error: readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream

Tags: post, wsgi, flask, dotcloud

I have facebook apps with flask with nginx and uwsgi. When it receive POST from facebook, it always has error:

```
readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream
```

But when I access my apps directly (with GET method), it ran smoothly. What I've done:

1. Limit @app.route with `POST` method only - doesn't work.
2. Add limit in wsgi: `uwsgi_buffer_size` (in case request from facebook is big), and `uwsgi_harakiri` (in case uwsgi provide timeout before finish it request) - doesn't work.

I have workaround in [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970495/nginx-connection-reset-response-from-uwsgi-lost) but can't figure out yet how to implement in flask. Could anyone help please?

Comment: the answer is bit ridiculous for me. I have to process all post data, even if my process is doing nothing. if "nothing" not in request.form: pass. Its working.. Btw, facebook open the app with POST request, so I should add that for every route. There must be better way of doing it..

Comment: If there is datas on a socket you have to read them (no other choices). On the flask wiki you can find a middleware to bypass this common problem on proxied setup: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/47/ uWSGI can help you with the --post-buffering option, but it is only a shortcut, nothing magic in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the bug of uwsgi. You can get more from [[uWSGI] Several bugs](http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2010-June/000448.html) .

The simple solution is that you must read the POST body by wsgi.input, even through POST body is null or you don't need POST params.

Comment: this has nothing to do with uWSGI (and it is certainly not a bug). Closing a socket without reading datas in it, is a wrong programming behaviour. uWSGI can help you (if you do not want to change your code) buffering post datas automatically via the --post-buffering option.

Comment: @roberto Thank you. When add post-buffering option in uwsgi setting, it works. But in some cases, for example, post request has no params, it's not need to read post body from wsgi.input. So I don't think it's the programmers' mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that "upstream" (the actual process that nginx is proxing) is closing the connection.

In my case, `Django` is my web server and I needed to set `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS` to be larger because there were too many fields in the POST request.