# uWSGI + nginx: request hangs if Content-Length specified

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, content-length

I am trying to set up a really simple uWSGI + nginx project. 
I ran into the following problems

1. `wsgi.input` appears to be empty (which I found out trying to get
   POST variables)
2. `curl http://localhost:8080/parsings` works fine, but `curl http://localhost:8080/parsings --header "Content-Length:1"` hangs and then returns `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`
3. Nothing appears on nginx `error.log`. uWSGI does not log anything either. It looks as if the request does not go anywhere near the server.

Here are the configs

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    proxy_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   10;
    proxy_send_timeout      15;
    proxy_read_timeout      20;
}
```

**sites-enabled/mysite**

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    server_name myproject.local;
    client_max_body_size 2M;

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/my_project.sock;
    }
}
```

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5
static-map = /static/=/home/breln/projects/myproject/static
socket = /tmp/my_project.sock
chmod-socket = 777
chown-socket = www-data
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Nginx is 1.11.8 (same problem appeared with 1.10.2). uWSGI is 2.0.14

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to uWSGI not buffering/reading the POST data from Nginx, unless your WSGI app tries to use the POST data in the request handler:

[Nginx connection reset, response from uWsgi lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970495/nginx-connection-reset-response-from-uwsgi-lost)